# Why does this print the memory location of an object rather than what I want?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure what's happening when I print my dictionary.

In Python 3, I have a dictionary of parse_blast objects called transSwiss. Each object's proteinID is the key with the entire object as the value.

I can print transSwiss in it's entirety and I can also print blasto.protein, but not when I combine them to get a dictionary value. I'm not sure what is happening when I use:

```
print(transSwiss[blasto.protein])
<__main__.parse_blast object at 0x000000373C5666A0>
```

Here is the code

```
class parse_blast(object):

    def __init__(self, line):
        #Strip end-of-line and split on tabs
        self.fields = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
        self.transcriptId, self.isoform = self.fields[0].split("|")
        self.swissStuff = self.fields[1].split("|")
        self.swissProtId = self.swissStuff[3]
        self.percentId = self.fields[2]

    def filterblast(self):
        return float(self.percentId) > 95



class parse_matrix(object):
    #Consider __init__ as a Constructor
    def __init__(self, matrix_lines):

        (self.protein, 
        self.Sp_ds, 
        self.Sp_hs, 
        self.Sp_log, 
        self.Sp_plat) = matrix_lines.strip("\n").split("\t")

    def separate_tuples(one_tuple):
        return "\t".join(one_tuple)


blastmap = map(parse_blast, blast_output.readlines())

filtered = filter(parse_blast.filterblast, blastmap)

matrixmap = map(parse_matrix, matrix_output.readlines()[1:])

transSwiss = {blasto.transcriptId:blasto for blasto in filtered}


for matrixo in matrixmap:

    print(transSwiss[matrixo.protein])
```

Comment: You need to define a `__str__` method.

Comment: Well, you're trying to print an object, which doesn't define `__str__`. What do you expect?

Comment: What do you want it to print out?

Comment: @MorganThrapp A ok I'll look into that, thank you.

Comment: Your `filter()` call also likely doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @deceze Ha I think it's obvious what I expected :) What is my filter() call doing?

Comment: `parse_blast.filterblast` should either be a static class method the way you're calling it right now, or you should call your filter in each instance like `filter(lambda b: b.filterblast(), ..)`.

Comment: @deceze thanks, I guess I don't understand why the filter function is wrong. It does seem to filter the way it is. Is it a question of efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your object is defined by you, you also need to tell python how you want it to print. You can do this by defining a function called "__str__" that returns how you want to print your object.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Classes#str

Comment: So the  "__ str __" function should contain anything that I would want to print?

Comment: Correct. Whenever python tries to print the object, it will essentially print whatever is returned by that function.